Build issue when building zlib using cmake, clangcl and visual studio 2022
I would like to build zlib using clangcl instead of VS2022 standard toolset. So i figured out that I can achieve this using -T option of cmake. It selects clang-cl correctly but I ran into some strange compile issues.
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\Llvm\x64\lib\clang\17\include\stddef.h(18): warning RC4067: unexpected characters following '#if/#elif' directive; newline expected 
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\Llvm\x64\lib\clang\17\include\vadefs.h(12): fatal error RC1021: invalid preprocessor command 'include_next' 

To reproduce the issue:

clone https://github.com/madler/zlib.git

Install VS 2022 and LLVM toolset + msbuild toolset (it should be clang 17)

create folder _build and enter _build

configure using the following command
cmake -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -T clangcl -DCMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY="MultiThreaded$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Debug>DLL" -DZLIB_BUILD_EXAMPLES:BOOL=OFF ..

build zlib
cmake --build .


You will get the warnings and error. Does anyone have an idea whats wrong here?
I tried other projects and these works perfectly fine using -T option. It seems only appear with zlib.
EDIT:
It works perfectly fine using cmake with clang on Linux, Android Ndk r26c on Windows and Linux and Msvc standard toolset.

Have you checked content of lines referenced in the warning and error messages? What is content of those lines?

The error is in the header as stated above. It is a #include_next directive to the same header to just go to the next file of the same name

The warning is a macro checks c++ module support.

I found the issue:
the compiler warnings/errors are produced by the zlib1.rc file. I just removed this file from being build. Now it works.
The basic problem seems to be that zlib does not have options to build static or shared libs separatly
